# Shiny *for* loop to automatically download plots

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2, shiny

i'm quite new to shiny, and am trying to make a shiny app which allows the user to download all possible combination of a certain data with a simple download button.

However, it seems that shiny isn't allowing a standard `for loop` that i've been using outside of shiny

so basically what I'm trying to do with this reproducible data is to allow users to download all 9 possible scatter plots `(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)` etc

I've tried using `lapply, isolate, local` and so on, but it simple would either make 3 of the same plots, or not work like the current code

Help would be very, very, very appreciated.

Thank you in advance

this is my current UI

```
#UI
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
Test1<- c(3,5,7)
Test2<- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
Test3<- c(600, 700, 800)
df <- data.frame(Test1, Test2, Test3)
rownames(df)<-colnames(df)
*ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Column Plot"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("First Type",
             pageWithSidebar(
               headerPanel('My First Plot'),
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', ""),
                 selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "", selected = ""),
                 actionButton(inputId = "clicks_3",label = "Real"),
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput('MyPlot')
               )
             )
    )
    
  )
)
)
```

this is my server

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({ 

    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'X Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df))
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Y Variable',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])
    
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    data()
  })
  output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- data()[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
    plot(x)
    
  })
  observeEvent(input$clicks_3,{
    for (i in 1:3){
      assign(paste("Plotinput_",i,sep = ""),({
        x <- data()[, c(colnames(data())[i], input$ycol)]
        plot(x)
      }))
      lapply(1:3, function(k){local({
        ggsave(plot = eval(parse(text=paste("Plotinput_",k,sep = ""))),filename = paste(k,"barplot.png",collapse = ""))
      })
      })
    }
  })
  
  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download all plots, I would recommend a markdown report solution. In there, you can use lapply and iterate over all your plots. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html

In your code, it seems the brackets are not correct, see part below for a solution

```
  observeEvent(input$clicks_3,{
    for (i in 1:3){
      assign(paste("Plotinput_",i,sep = ""),({
        x <- data()[, c(colnames(data())[i], input$ycol)]
        plot(x)
      }))
    }
    lapply(1:3, function(k){local({
      ggsave(plot = eval(parse(text=paste("Plotinput_",k,sep = ""))),filename = paste(k,"barplot.png",collapse = ""))
    })
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, it works great :), first time using markdown but it seems very handy

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if it solves your question